# Dynamics CRM 2013 updates to Price List Items are not reflected in the General view

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, and have a quandry. I have a product that is sold in 3 currencies (and 2 different unit groups, but the unit groups should not affect this), and I wish to update the prices for those three currencies. So, the simple way to do this should be through the Sales -> Products screen, and then in the Price List Items menu I should update the prices for the three different currencies. This is correct so far, right? However, when I do this, the List Price box in the Product's general screen will retain the earlier price for the item.

For example, for item Toy Car, the price in the past was $99.99 (I do not remember the exact source for the price). I update that price in the Price List Items screen so that the "Amount (Base)" column for the USD price is $10, the CAD price is 20, and the EUR price is 30. USD is the default currency. I expect the List Price on the general screen to show $10 after I make these updates. But it doesn't, it keeps the $99.99 instead.

What am I doing wrong? Does that List Price pull from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The List Price attribute on the product form has no relationship with the Price List Items.

You need some kind of custom automation to bring over the value (I'd say a plugin on create/update of Price List Items, just to name one option).

Comment: Thanks! We have a custom automation; we assumed that it had broken some link between the List Price and the Price List Items.
So what is the point of Price List Items if it doesn't connect to anything? This seems like a needless source of confusion.